# Django Admin(Blog) отправка поста с оформлением текста

Tags: django, django-admin

Есть блог. Например, я пишу статью в своем блоге. В статье имеются предложения, которые я хочу выделить тегом . Поставить пробелы там где мне надо и чтобы Django сохранил это так, как написал я. А не так как делает он по умолчанию. 
Возможно ли передать текст в тегах html и чтобы он сохранял их не буквально, а как разметку. Например в ROR есть `activeadmin`, который поддерживает данную функциональность. Возможно ли здесь такое? Просто не вижу смысла отправлять сухой текст, без стилевого оформления.

For example: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете использовать любой из WYSIWIG редакторов(смотрите внимательно на версию Python). От себя могу порекомендовать [CKEditor](https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#).

Их список и подробное сравнение можно найти тут: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/wysiwyg/